# How to debug with PDT, XDebug, Slim Framework, Chrome Advance Rest User

Tags: php, google-chrome, rest, cookies

I'm trying to create a RESTful web service with Slim Framework and I user the Chrome Advanced Rest Client extension to test the REST web service.

I'm new with debugging in PHP, I've been trying to setup a debug environment with PDT, XDebug. I've successfully enable the debugging in PDT with XDebug. Now, I want to try to trigger XDebug from the Chrome Advanced Rest Client. Is it possible?

I've been searching for the way to do it and I found this link:
[XDebug and RESTful server using PHPStorm or POSTman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139803/xdebug-a-restful-server-using-phpstorm-or-postman)
.

Is it true that we have to add XDebug query string at the back of the web service url and set the XDebug cookie at the request header? (I've tried but I fail because I don't know how to set the cookie)

Thank you,
Suwandi C.