# Have Xdebug stop at a breakpoint when handling HTML requests

Tags: php, request, phpstorm, xdebug

I want to debug an API function that handles an HTTP POST request. My PHPstorm is set up to work with the Chrome browser extension, and works fine.

When I manually create a POST request, using Postman or PHPStorm's own REST testing tool, there's no Xdebug header being sent though, and I can't break within the function handling that request.

Manually adding XDEBUG_SESSION_START="PHPSTORM" to the request header didn't help. Is there maybe another way to debug such a request that's not initiated by the browser?

**Update:**
I've tried cookies as well, capturing them from Chrome (see below). No difference.
[image]

Comment: *"Manually adding XDEBUG_SESSION_START="PHPSTORM" to the request header didn't help."* What "request header"? It has to be either query string or POST data. Try using cookie instead (work fine).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19147935/783119

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` To the headers instead

Comment: Had no success with that. I even captured the cookies form Chrome, using "Postman Interceptor", no difference.

Comment: @Lars Well, in such case `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your `php.ini`. NOTE that it will attempt to debug **every single** request processed by PHP interpreter that uses that php.ini. Alternatively -- add `xdebug_break();` in actual PHP code...

Answer (score 0):

Putting `XDEBUG_SESSION_START="PHPSTORM"` into the **body** of the request did the trick.

Seems I've missed that the first time I tried it, because I had created a new debug environment without realising path mappings where missing.

Strangely enough, setting the cookies did nothing.