# PhpStorm Xdebug command line

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I cannot get a curl request fired from a Vagrant instance on my machine to fire Xdebug breakpoints in my code in PhpStorm. Everything works correctly when I instantiate a request from my browser, but I need to debug an external API call into my system and I am using command line curl to do this.

So this line:

```
curl -v -i -X POST -d '{"data":"thisisatest"}' http://<myhost>/api/MeasureOne/upeOne/uploadTranscripEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM
```

does not work. It does not trigger the breakpoints in PhpStorm.

Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: Use Postman/Insomnia or alike to make API calls? It's much easier this way. Pass "debug me" flag via cookie instead of GET parameter. It works fine here... PhpStorm also has the RESTful client built-in -- try using it. **P.S.** I hope your real curl line has proper parameters .. because current one is obviously broken and "debug me" xdebug flag is not passed anywhere (it's simply not there)

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147935/783119 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Built-in+REST+Client+in+PhpStorm 3) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm