# How debug client request in PhpStorm

Tags: php, debugging, server, phpstorm

Hi I have a problem with PhpStorm debugger. I'm writing a web service in PHP and when I start client to ask for a service the server responses with no problem to client but despite I'm in debug mode it doesn't debug (example it doesn't stop at break point).

Debug work right when the url request come from browser but not when it comes from a client (that can be a simple program in Java that try to call some service).

Comment: You need to either pass "debug me" flag via COOKIE or GET/POST parameter ( https://xdebug.org/docs/remote ) or configure Xdebug to try to debug **every single request** https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_autostart).  Another option is to add programmatic breakpoint by placing `xdebug_break();` into your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XDebug and RESTful server using PHPStorm or POSTman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139803/xdebug-and-restful-server-using-phpstorm-or-postman)