# Debug Behat scenarios does not work stop in real code, why?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, behat

I am trying to set up and debug Behat scenarios through PhpStorm but I cannot get it working so far. By scenarios I mean I would expect the debugger stops in the real code, not in a Context file which actually it does. I am using Docker and PHP 8.0.x with Xdebug 3.0.4. Here is what I have done:

1. Setup the PHP Interpreter (nothing weird here, just follow the usual steps to register a new interpreter)

   [image]
2. Setup Behat testing tool

   [image]
3. Right-click on the scenario I want to test which creates a Run configuration:

   [image]

   [image]
4. Adding a breakpoint in any Context file used in the scenario makes the debugger to stops when I hit the small green bug icon (the one next to the green play button)

   [image]

But from there, the debugger never reaches the real code, which I would like to debug (and yes I have several breakpoints in the real code).

Useful information:

Xdebug is enabled and is configured as follow (taken from `php -i`):

```
Version => 3.0.4
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support
           
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Aids => ✔ enabled
Coverage => ✘ disabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

Debugger => enabled
IDE Key => PHPSTORM

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => host.docker.internal => host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.coverage_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.log => /tmp/xdebug.log => /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.mode => develop,debug => develop,debug
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.overload_var_dump => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.start_with_request => yes => yes
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

The request (in this case is a POST) is being sent using Guzzle as following and as you can see I have set a Cookie for the `XDEBUG_SESSION`

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleHttpClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$this->httpClient = new GuzzleHttpClient(['cookies' => true]);

$request = new Request($method, $url, $this->storage()->get('headers'));
$options = [
    'verify' => false,
    'on_stats' => [$this, 'guzzleRequestStats'],
    'headers' => ["Cookie" => "XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM"]
];

$this->httpClient->sendAsync($request, $options);
```

When debugging the Behat scenario through PhpStorm this is what is written to the console:

```
php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9003 -dxdebug.client_host=172.17.0.1 -d xdebug.start_with_request=yes /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/behat.php --format PhpStormBehatFormatter --no-interaction --suite=default --format=progress --config /var/www/framework/behat.yml /var/www/framework/features/check_status.feature:6
```

And Xdebug writes the following to logs:

```
[183] Log opened at 2021-07-25 18:34:18.374219
[183] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[183] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[183] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///tmp/dbgHITriA" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.8" protocol_version="1.0" appid="183"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[183] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n notify_ok -v 1
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- stdout -i 7 -c 1
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="7" success="1"></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- status -i 8
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="8" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- step_into -i 9
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="9" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///tmp/dbgHITriA" lineno="5"></xdebug:message></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 10 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="10"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[1]]></property></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 11 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="11"><property type="string" size="25" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[c2VydmVyTmFtZT1hcGkuZWxpbnZvLmNvbQ==]]></property></response>

[183] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 12
[183] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="12" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: 1) What is  "real code" here? Where is it located / how it's called from your tests? 2) What *"The request is being sent using Guzzle as follow:"* has to do with this? 3) Please clarify the relation between "scenarios" and the "real code". As I understand you do have some API calls in your Behat tests to the API (the real code) .. and `GuzzleHttpClient` used to make such API calls?

Comment: You initiate a debugging session for the CLI run by hitting the Debug button in PhpStorm, but whatever you call with Guzzle is being executed by the web server's PHP module and it has no idea you had an intention to debug this code. You need to start Xdebug for the web server [automatically](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#activate_debugger) or enable it by adding the debug cookie or GET-parameter to the request.

Comment: @LazyOne (3) you are getting this correct, the Behat Context is just a wrapper to send a request to the API (real code) through `GuzzleHttpClient`. Also `real code` means anything outside the Behat Context files which is "not" real code just a wrapper for a step in my case.

Comment: @ReynierPM See what EugeneMorozov said: you are debugging the Behat tests (done via CLI environment). Guzzle makes API request via web environment ... and I doubt you are adding Xdebug cookie/"debug me" parameter to such requests. It's a separate /unrelated request in PHP/Xdebug eyes and it needs that "debug me" param to initiate another debug session (or Xdebug must be configured in advance to automatically try to debug every single request).

Comment: @ReynierPM Why not debug the API requests separately anyway. Use appropriate type of Run/Debug Configuration (e.g. [PHP HTTP Request](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configuration-php-http-request.html) or perhaps [HTTP Client](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html) to make such requests right from PhpStorm (Debug button will work for them as well). Or use Postman for that (and add Xdebug cookie there to the request) -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147935/783119

Comment: @ReynierPM Another possible (but rather inconvenient) alternative: already mentioned configure Xdebug to try to debug every single request automatically: `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#start_with_request. And just a reminder: there can be separate php.ini files used by CLI and web server on most of the modern Linux/Macs setups. Which means; if it works in CLI it does not automatically means that it's also configured for web (API).

Comment: @LazyOne the Behat test is the one setting up the data I need to be able to successfully hit the API and obtain a result, hitting the API directly is not an option here unless I add the same data to the DB :( I am trying with Eugene solution but is not working either. I forgot to mention that I am using PHP-PM (https://github.com/php-pm/php-pm) and not Apache and/or Nginx

Comment: @LazyOne tried also the PHP HTTP Request and is not working either :(

Comment: Without having an access to the project and your setup, for now I can only suggest the following: 1) create custom API endpoint and return `xdebug_info()` output (or Xdebug section of phpinfo()`) -- this is to double check your Xdebug config under php-fpm. 2) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it will write there (try that for the already working Behat tests) -- it will show where it tries to debug and what the response is. If it does not write anything: Xdebug either does not see "debug me" flag, unable to write to that location or the real path to file is different (virtual temp)

Comment: @LazyOne I have added some more context info still I am unable to debug the API code properly :(

Comment: 1) Just to be clear: that log is generated after you execute that Guzzle code call, right (so it's for debugging the API)? 2) The log says that the file in question (the one being debugged) is `/tmp/dbgHITriA` -- I don't think IDE can map such "random file name in a temp folder" to any file inside the project... Basically, the file is unknown to IDE as it cannot map it. Look into that first. The `fileuri=` in first Xdebug response line should point to a "valid" path.

Comment: 1) that's the entire log when I try to debug the API call, 2) not sure how to deal with the filename since that is being "autogenerated" by PHPPM I guess since mappings are correct

Comment: 1) Sorry, No idea what you mean by "autogenerated by PHPFPM". As far as I know php-fpm it just handles your PHP workers; it does not make custom PHP files for you. If it does: I know nothing about that then. 2) Try disabling "start_with_request" .. and put `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code/some test API endpoint (so the debug session will be initiated when that line is executed and not on the first script start) -- will there be any difference in the log/behaviour?

Comment: 3) Also try adding custom code instead of that line and dump the stack frame (to get more info on how the request being processed)

Comment: (1) you are miss reading here, is not PHP FPM, it is PHP PM (see https://github.com/php-pm/php-pm)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235289/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-lazyone).

Comment: Sorry -- did never heard of PHP PM before. I've never run PHP code in async manner, only under traditional Apache/nginx/IIS or PHP's web server. The GitHub page says that it should be possible to debug the code with PhpStorm and Xdebug .. but that temp file -- no idea where it comes from and how it's ments to be debugged with such file. I may only suggest looking into the latest #2 and #3 -- maybe it will give some hints. Look like I'm not able to be of much help here.