# Laravel Sail - debug API with Xdebug

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug, laravel-sail

I'm using Laravel Sail for my development environment and I'm wanting to use Xdebug to debug my PHP Laravel code.

I've set up Xdebug as per the documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#debugging-with-xdebug

However, the documentation only shows how to Xdebug from a browser or debugging CLI commands, what about APIs? If I set a breakpoint in my PHP code and use Postman to send an API request it does not hit any breakpoints. As a quick test, I opened my browser with the Xdebug extension and typed in the API url, the breakpoint works.

This is NOT the way I want to be debugging my code, I can't debug my APIs properly because they require certain parameters and body contents with certain headers which I can't do in a browser.

So this begs the question, how do you APIs using Xdebug in Laravel Sail?

Comment: *"If I set a breakpoint in my PHP code and use Postman to send an API request it does not hit any breakpoints. "* Add Xdebug cookie to your request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147935/783119

Comment: Thanks for asking this @Courtney White, I'm also experiencing the same exact issue and can't find a way to make it work, especially for backend API calls.

Answer (score 3):

You can do one of two things:

1. Set the `XDEBUG_SESSION=somevalue` cookie with your API call.
2. Change (or add) the `xdebug.start_with_request` setting to `yes` (instead of the default, which is `trigger`). Use `xdebug_info()` to find out which ini file to change.

Comment: Hi @Derick, mind if you show me how to do item #2, please?